# Undefined index: sSearch jQuery Datatables Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, datatables

**EDIT** As some answer suggests, I am aware that this error occurs because the variable is non existent and is not passed. Question is how do I configure this for Datatables, I believe thos variable should came from my Ajax code as variable but how do I set it or what is the proper format in codes for it to work?

I am working on jQuery Datatables library using Postgre SQL and following this link.

https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_postgres

I followed is correctly and I believe that the database connection is good.

But I am getting this error:

```
Undefined index: sSearch
```

I am using Laravel 5.1 and I have a view which I fetch data via Ajax then populating it in jQuery datatables. I used the server side  method: My code:

```
public function apiGetCustomers()
{

    $aColumns = array( 'id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'gender', 'phone_num', 'country', 'postcode' );

    $sIndexColumn = "id";

    $sTable = "customers";

    $gaSql['user']       = "postgres";
    $gaSql['password']   = "postgres";
    $gaSql['db']         = "qms";
    $gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

    $gaSql['link'] = pg_connect(
        " host=".$gaSql['server'].
        " dbname=".$gaSql['db'].
        " user=".$gaSql['user'].
        " password=".$gaSql['password']
    ) or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    $sLimit = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
    {
        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] )." OFFSET ".
            intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] );
    }

    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                    ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc').", ";
            }
        }

        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
            {
                $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." ILIKE '%".pg_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
            }
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ")";
    }

    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." ILIKE '%".pg_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
        }
    }

    $sQuery = "
    SELECT ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
    ";
    $rResult = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());

    $sQuery = "
        SELECT $sIndexColumn
        FROM   $sTable
    ";
    $rResultTotal = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());
    $iTotal = pg_num_rows($rResultTotal);
    pg_free_result( $rResultTotal );

    if ( $sWhere != "" )
    {
        $sQuery = "
            SELECT $sIndexColumn
            FROM   $sTable
            $sWhere
        ";
        $rResultFilterTotal = pg_query( $gaSql['link'], $sQuery ) or die(pg_last_error());
        $iFilteredTotal = pg_num_rows($rResultFilterTotal);
        pg_free_result( $rResultFilterTotal );
    }
    else
    {
        $iFilteredTotal = $iTotal;
    }

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "aaData" => array()
    );

    while ( $aRow = pg_fetch_array($rResult, null, PGSQL_ASSOC) )
    {
        $row = array();
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
            else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
            {
                /* General output */
                $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
        }
        $output['aaData'][] = $row;
    }

     echo json_encode( $output );

    // Free resultset
    pg_free_result( $rResult );

    // Closing connection
    pg_close( $gaSql['link'] );

}
```

The Ajax in my view

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#CustomerList').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "api/customer/all",
        "paging" : true,
        //"scrollY" : 400,
        "searching" : true,
        "ordering" :  true,
        //"pagingType" : "full_numbers" 
    } );
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @Epodax I am aware of if. I revised my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an 1.9.x serverside script but are using the 1.10.x naming conventions and options layout. When you have defined

```js
serverSide: true,
ajax: "api/customer/all",
```

etc, you also instruct dataTables to sent params to the server in the newer format, i.e `search` instead of `sSearch` and so forth. The easiest way to overcome this issue is to force dataTables AJAX handling into [**legacy mode**](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Legacy) :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But where $.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true; will go in my code?

Comment: @JoeneFloresca - as a single line, **before** you initialise the dataTable, i.e before `$('#CustomerList').DataTable( { `

Comment: Works fine now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['sSearch']) && !empty($_GET['search']))
```

you try to call a variable that maybe doesn't exists.

Comment: Hi. I am aware of that, I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: I think `Datatable`will add it to the url so you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting display_errors to Off in php.ini helped me. I would suggest to try it as well.

Comment: Why was my answer downgraded? This fix worked for me!